# how to set html5's required to a text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

iI it possible to set **required** to a text field using jquery or JavaScript. i need this because the text field will be visible to a user only if he selects yes to a question through checkbox,and when i make the textfield visible through jquery using its id ,i also want to make it **required**.I tried making the field required manually in the tag by adding **required** but its creating a problem for me if a user selects no to the question that makes the textfield visible.

Comment: Please share your code (or fiddle it)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, using jQuery you can do it like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').prop('required', true)
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dhq8L0ym/)**

Or with plain JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('text').required = true;
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0q05dk5n/)**